# PYREBASE - I have an APIKey for someone's firebase app, and I want to see the files inside their storage bucket

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, pyrebase

using python3 pyrebase module:
I know some of the file names and I can access them by `storage.child()`, But I want to get the full list of files on the storage.
I tried

```
    import pyrebase
    
    config = {
      "apiKey": "apiKey",
      "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
      "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
      "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com"
    }
    
    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
```

and

```
storage = firebase.storage()
files = storage.list_files()
```

but it still returns

```
AttributeError: 'Storage' object has no attribute 'bucket'
```

Again, I do not own the firebase DB and I still have the API key, not the serviceAccount json file.

UPDATE: I have extracted and authorization bearer key. Can I use it for authorize login?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/97) you need to add service account credentials to your config as described [here](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#add-pyrebase-to-your-application).

You can create and download key following [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys).

Comment: The problem is I'm not using my own firebase. kinda trying to break in!

Comment: You need to authenticate somehow, ask owner for service account credentials.

Comment: HAHA that's not gonna happen. but I have a "bearer" key. can that be useful?